# Share Button In Facebook Messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to create a CardAction (button) in botframework which works as a share button in Facebook Messenger?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Share button is specific to Facebook and not common to all the channels, there isn't code in the BotBuilder for doing that.

However it can be achieved, by using `ChannelData` (`C#`)/ `sourceEvent` (`Node.js`).

See [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1714) as reference on how the channel data info should looks like. Also, [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ChannelData) shows how to use the `ChannelData` feature.

Finally, here is the documentation around [ChannelData](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/channeldata/#navtitle).

Comment: All of these sources are know to me and so general. To improve your response, please provide a link which implements share button using ChannelData in C#. It would be so helpful as a response.

Comment: I don't recall of a sample implementing Share button in C# but it would be as easy as take the code from the node.js sample in the link and port it to C#... I don't have the bandwith currently to write the code for you; but with the information I provided should be really straighforward

Comment: Indeed, it's not straightforward in practice! When you implement the sample it would be so helpful and might be found it would not straightforward!

Comment: Why it;s not straightforward? What issue are you hitting? In the ChannelData sample I linked we are using the AirlineCheckIn facebook native feature for example.

Comment: I've gotten some error in setting share button when using channel data,  I think this bug might come from the botframework, but not sure (it might be reported in the near future when I will sure about it). Anyhow, the straightforward example would be helpful!

Comment: Any ideas on how I can add this if i want to share a plain text message and not a card?

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of the information provided by Ezequiel,

I have created a working C# bot that utilizes the `ChannelData` property to send a Share Button over Facebook Messenger.

Feel free to [check out the repo here.](https://github.com/Fignewton5/Azure_Bot_FB_ChannelData_CSharp/tree/master/Azure_Bot_Generic_CSharp)

The `Models` directory contains all the class definitions that will act as the proper JSON format for a Facebook Messenger Share Button [as is documented here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/share-button#implementation)

Then you just create a new object using all of your combined Model classes and assign it to the `ChannelData` property of a new reply in your dialog like so:

From `ShareButtonDialog.cs`:

```
namespace Azure_Bot_Generic_CSharp
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Models;

    [Serializable]
    public class ShareButtonDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;

            //create a reply message
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            //create a channel data object to act as a facebook share button
            reply.ChannelData = new FacebookChannelData()
            {
                Attachment = new FacebookAttachment()
                {
                    Payload = new FacebookGenericTemplate()
                    {
                        Elements = new object[]
                        {
                            new FacebookGenericTemplateContent()
                            {
                                Buttons = new[]
                                {
                                    new FacebookShareButton()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            //send message
            await context.PostAsync(reply);

            var reply2 = context.MakeMessage();
            reply2.Text = "This is a message after the Share Button template.";
            await context.PostAsync(reply2);
            //wait for more messages to be sent here
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

That will produce the desired output:

[image]

**Please note that you will need to fill in your own Bot App ID and Secret in the Web.config file if you plan to use the project.**

Comment: Any ideas on how I can add this if i want to share a plain text message and not a card?